# Node Cron not execute on heroku server

Tags: node.js, heroku, firebase-cloud-messaging, node-cron

I have an application backend with express node deployed on heroku server.  My backend application has a scheduling using node-cron.  I set a schedule to send notifications with FCM every 7 a.m., but at 7 a.m. no notifications came in and I checked the logs on heroku server, nothing happened there (previously I wrote `console.log` on apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with the timezone you have set for the cron scheduler.

Try converting 7a.m. to UTC timezone and run the scheduler again.

Comment: when I tried it on localhost everything went well

Comment: Localhost often uses the current timezone you are usually in. For server side, the default UTC timezone is normally used. That said, you can look into configuring the right timezone to run your cron scheduler on.

Comment: hmm, interesting. I looked at the logs on heroku server and it shows 13 o'clock but now it's 20 (Indonesia). I'll try it first, thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using the free version of Heroku.

Heroku applications will go to a state of inactivity if it goes on for thirty minutes without receiving any traffic. This is done to preserve your free dyno hours.

One way to solve this is to create a cronjob in a Linux machine (preferably microcomputers like Raspberry Pi because it is low-powered) that will perform a `GET` request minutes before the `node-cron` runs. This will prevent the instance from going to sleep. It is recommended to make a dedicated endpoint for connection tests.

Example:

- We edit the crontab first.

```sh
crontab -e
```

- Let's say you want to make a `GET` request every 06:55.

```sh
55 6 * * * curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET <YOUR_WEBSERVER_CONNECTION_TEST_ENDPOINT_LINK>
```

References:

- [Free Dyno Hours on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours)
- [Crontab Syntax](https://crontab.guru/)

Comment: I also create a cron job to ping my backend application every 25 minutes so that the server doesn't sleep, but it still doesn't work